# Using an textbox ID from another .ASPX file to a .CS file

Tags: c#, variables

So I have this ID `UserNameTextBox` and it is in a .ASPX file, I want to use that same ID in this set of code for a .CS file:

```
private static ApplicationUser CreateDefualtUser() {
            return new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = UserNameTextBox,
                FirstName = Fname,
                LastName = Lname,
                Email = email,
                AvatarUrl = "~/Content/Photo/custom.jpg"
            };
        }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you want to get the text from the TextBox object, you should access the Text property: UserNameTextBox.Text

Comment: But the thing is that they are in 2 different files and one file is an ASPX file, and another is a C# file.

Comment: Is the C# file the code-behind file for the ASPX file? E.g. Do they files have the same name, but one is .aspx and the other .cs? If so then the .cs file should have access to all objects declared in the .aspx file. If not, then you will need to extract the  values from the .aspx file in the code-behind .cs file for the page, and then pass those values into the CreateDefaultUser function.

Comment: And how do I extract it? Sorry, I am not very good at C# or ASPX.

Comment: So you should have a file called something like MyPage.aspx and then another file called MyPage.cs or MyPage.aspx.cs . The MyPage.cs class has access to the TextBox object in the MyPage.aspx file. But other classes outside of MyPage can't access the TextBox. So inside the MyPage class you'll have to access UserNameTextBox.Text and then if CreateDefaultUser is in another class, pass that value to it as a function parameter.